# Weird margin issue with relative layout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have a TextView to fill the space between a button on the left and the edge of the layout on the right.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcomeHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setInfusionReminder"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome!" />
```

What I am seeing in the editor however is `android:layout_marginRight` is applied on the left. The end result is 40dp margin on the left and 0 margin on the right.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `android:layout_gravity="center"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the following attributes that don't quite work together as you'd expect:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/setInfusionReminder"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Sidenote: Atleast from what I've seen in my own projects, it tends to make the element somewhat uncontrollable for further layout-related attributes.

Update to address the comment:

I'd probably do the following:

```
1. Remove the android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
2. Set the android:layout_width to "fill_parent"
3. Keep the gravity at android:gravity => "center"
```

This should make it expand as much as possible to the right, while centering the content (text).

Comment: Yes, using "fill_parent" instead of attaching it to left and right works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you using both `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setInfusionReminder"` . Remove the `android:layout_alignParentRight` and try it should work as you like.

```
     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/welcomeHeader"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSettkoff"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome!" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to center the text over the space between button and the right edge. Removing `android:layout_alignParentRight` makes text stick to the button.

Comment: I updated the answer which working for me (tested ).. Try this